# Error trying to call pkill chrome in python (ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I have a webscraper in selenium. This is on ubuntu (EC2), so a linux environment. I want to make sure I'm killing all chrome processes after the script runs, so at the end of the driver session, I'm invoking `pkill chrome`

Here's my basic python script:

```
#set driver options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)

#Do some stuff.............

#Kill webdriver
driver.quit()

#Kill chrome
tmp = os.system("pkill /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable") 
print(tmp)
if tmp!=0:
    print('not sucessfull')
else:
    print("Task succesfully killed")
```

I've also tried:

```
 tmp = os.system("pkill chrome")
```

and

```
tmp = os.system("pkill google-chrome-stable")
```

and

```
tmp = subprocess.call("TASKKILL /f  /IM  /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable.EXE")
```

The problem is that the `pkill chrome` command is failing. The error code that `tmp` is printing is `256`. Can anyone tell me what the issue here is?  `pkill chrome` seems to work fine from the command line itself, just not in the python script.

Comment: Was there any issue when you used driver.quit() - it'll simply kill all windows opened by selenium for that particular execution

Comment: My issue is that there still seems to be memory leak.  My selenium code will crash intermittently with this error: 'Unable to open X display and unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally'. I believe this is due to low memory/disk space. Running pkill chrome from the terminal pretty consistently fixes the crash, but I don't want to have to run that command manually. I either want to run pkill chrome from python script or linux crontab.